# setMissingLast in PECL Solr

Tags: php, solr, pecl

Problem:
Items have optional price. If the price is 0 (or I can change it to null if it helps), then when displaying documents, those documents need to be sorted last when sorting by price. After long searching I think setMissingLast would help most, but I don't see any way of setting setMissingLast option in PECL Solr (and we can't change a search library just for this thing).

I also tried without success to use map(price,0,0,999) function query (only when sorting ascending).

How can I set setMissingLast for price field in PECL Solr, or are there any other solutions for making sure missing price documents are always sorted last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `sortMissingLast`. You don't need your library to support it, you just have to add `sortmissingLast=true` in your fieldType definition within the [solr schema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Data_Types).